# Do I glue luxury vinyl flooring ON or UNDER angled, metal threshold that transitions exterior to interior kitchen floor?

Tags: flooring, installation, vinyl-flooring

I’m installing LVF, gluing to wood floor (tongue & groove flooring). There is an angled piece of metal the width of the threshold, transitioning the exterior threshold into the kitchen.

My question is do I glue the LVF under the metal transition or over (or glue to floor and glue a strip on top of metal? Or best to paint metal)? Again, the metal transitions the exterior threshold into interior kitchen, the metal angled so as to alleviate a slight drop down into kitchen. Thoughts and / or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your LVF is supposed to be glued down ? Transition strips go over the flooring. A photo would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, it’s luxury “vinyl” flooring (planks) with the product’s glue (Karndean Product). Thank you for responding so quickly,

Comment: OK. thanks.  UnhandledExcepSean's answer is correct. Choose it as correct if you agree.

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the transition strip and place the new flooring down and put the transition piece back on. If you glue something on top of the transition piece, it will be a trip hazard and will, in a short time, come loose.